# using self-signed certificates with requests in python

Tags: python-2.7, https, openssl, python-requests

**Situation :**
The target site (a pre-prod URL, say https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login, for example) is using a self-signed certificate. 
From the browser, the site is accessible over https without any issues (the self-signed certificate warning is suppressed by adding the certificate to the trust store in the browser)

**Problem Statement :**
A simple python script that makes a get call to the target site using requests fails with either of the below errors in different situations :

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:344: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

or

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
>   The simple script used (on the python prompt) is :

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login')
```

**Things already tried **

1. I do **NOT** want to skip the ssl verification. Hence, verify = false is not an option for me.
2. I have already used the below with the same error

`res = requests.get('https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login', verify = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test.pem')` where test.pem is a pem file created by concatenating the output of the below commands in that order :

> openssl rsa -in ~/Desktop/CertPath/private.key -check

and

> openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in ~/Desktop/CertPath/certificate.pem

The script is run from ~/Desktop/CertPath so getcwd() gives the right path to the certificate.

3. I tried another test.pem file as well where the order of concatenation  was reversed. It still throws the same error.
4. Have tried passing the .pem file holding the public key and the .key file holding the private key, separately (individually) as well, with the same error as the outcome.

**Environment details if it helps**

OS - ElCapitan Mac
Requests - 2.9.0
Python - 2.7.10
OpenSSL being used by Python - 'OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015'

Note - The openssl version does not seem to be an issue. Because even with an updated version of openssl, the errors are the same - tested on Ubuntu 
with Python 2.6 that uses the Openssl 1.x

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you can use Let's Encrypt? And your dev configuration will be closer to your prod.

Answer (score 6):

This question is old but In case someone wonders off here.

You are putting the private key and public key in you test.pem. This is wrong. What verify param requires is certs which it can trust.

```
res = requests.get('https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login', verify = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test.pem')
```

The test.pem is supposed to contain the list of all the Trusted Certificates. But what you're providing in your test.pem is your public and private key. You're ~/Desktop/CertPath/certificate.pem file itself should go into it.

Try this:

```
res = requests.get('https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login', verify = '~/Desktop/CertPath/certificate.pem')
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to [specify certificate for SSL verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) you can use :

```
requests.get('https://my-pre-prod-site.com/login', cert=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test.pem'))
```

Comment: have tried that already. Does not work. The same error persists.