# Add single certificate to requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a corporate intranet HTTPS server, which uses an in-house CA, from within Python/requests running on a Linux machine.  I have a .pem file that contains our certificate (4096 bit RSA, CSSM_KEYUSE_VERIFY, CA = true).

I put this into a subfolder of `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` in order to integrate it in the system.

In the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), I found:

> You can pass verify the path to a CA_BUNDLE file or directory with certificates of trusted CAs … If verify is set to a path to a directory, the directory must have been processed using the c_rehash utility supplied with OpenSSL.

I believe (but am not sure) that `/etc/ssl/certs` fulfills this condition.

Now, I tried requests in various ways:

```py
requests.get(download_url)
# throws requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([
#   ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate',
#    'certificate verify failed')],)",)

requests.get(download_url, verify = False)
# works, but is obviously bad (and spits out a warning)

requests.get(download_url, verify = pem_file_path)
# same SSLError as above (option shows no effect)

requests.get(download_url, cert = pem_file_path)
requests.get(download_url, cert = '/etc/ssl/certs')
# both throw OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [
#   ('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'),
#   ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]

requests.get(download_url, verify = '/etc/ssl/certs')
# Finally, this raises an unprintable exception:
# requests.exceptions.SSLError: <exception str() failed>
```

Actually, [using self-signed certificates with requests in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767484/using-self-signed-certificates-with-requests-in-python) looks like it could describe the same problem (but is not answered yet).

Comment: You're getting an SSL error so first verify your own with openssl https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html

Comment: You were right.  The problem was with the certificate, not with the way I tried using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @stark, I found out that the problem was that my certificate file was expired.  With the correct, up-to-date certificate (even in DER format, with the .cer extension), the following syntax now works:

```
requests.get(download_url, verify = cer_file_path)
```

Comment: Can you elarborate a bit more? I'm having the same problem right now, but I've download the pem file certificate online. How do I find out it it's expired or bad? And where can I find a good one?

Comment: Oh, yes, the link is dead, I see. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/how-can-i-verify-ssl-certificates-on-the-command-line could help, maybe? As far as I can see, I just used ``openssl verify /path/to/my.pem``.